# TypeScript Merge N Objects Preserving Types

Tags: typescript, object, generics, merge

Given an arbitrary number of objects of different shape, is it possible for TypeScript to properly assert type information?

Example:

```js
const merge = (...objects) => {
  return Object.values(objects).reduce((acc, next) => ({ ...acc, ...next }));
}
```

My actual use case is a lot more involved than this, but the type signature would be similar.

Here's what works, but I hope is not the only solution:

```
function merge<T1, T2>(...objects: [T1, T2]): T1 & T2;
function merge<T1, T2, T3>(...objects: [T1, T2, T3]): T1 & T2 & T3;
function merge(...objects) {
  return Object.values(objects).reduce((acc, next) => ({ ...acc, ...next }));
}
```

My issues with this are that it fails to compile with the newer versions of TypeScript and it's not at all maintainable.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: That's not the syntax I was struggling with, in fact if you look at my example, the same is achieved with `T1 & T2...`.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple more rounds of experimenting, here's a solution, that albeit works - I'd still like to see some improvement upon:

```
function merge<R>(...objects: Partial<R>[]): R {
  return Object.values(objects).reduce((acc, next) => ({ ...acc, ...next }));
}
```

It approaches the issue from the other side - defining the return type and the signature qualifies any partial implementations of what's returned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way to implement the function is using `Object.assign()`, and a more complicated way to type the function that works a bit better since the generic type can be inferred:

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwjpAhgYwNYHsBuBTAJwDMAbbAdwDp1sBbYVYAVgAYBmAdmYCYAOAGzAe7AJx9WPVgChIATxj5QAVQB2AS2yqAKtgCSqyETj50kTaoA8ygHygAvKAAUy0PgAeR1QBM4oVKpyoAD8zpgIKgCUDna42OreoBGq+ASE0R5evs5O4aDqqsREoHrR9rHx3tGhekmgKWkA3NLSxACuqmYWoHREAOb4ltpunvg+fgDeAL4A2gC6Nk5Uy9gARgBWppCIoNqREWoWugZGhCZdWkMzqm10q0QLoBPSoK+ghPiQbYSqoADyGy2VFQcDg6j6qic0wANKBllQ1pszHBIs0pi1aKoUKB3A4ev18FDQMRsNgIsxQFNYRNQKtUIQIgByCjYQikbyMynU0AARza7giM1AAEZWLDGSDvMROXNKajpCBQJjsQKngqwG9iaTkrd7oRmoqpqAAGRqxWaukM0AoQgFPoGsBG03Pc1vPmqpw2u2gAA+9V1REi8wdlOkQA)

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2398020
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

function merge<T extends {}[]>(...objects: T): UnionToIntersection<T[number]> {
    return Object.assign({}, ...objects);
}

const x = merge({ foo: 5 }, { bar: 'world' }, { qux: [ 10, 'asdf' ] });
// const x: {
//     foo: number;
// } & {
//     bar: string;
// } & {
//     qux: (string | number)[];
// }
```

Note however, if there are duplicate keys it may not type them correctly (it should have the later objects override the former)

```
const y = merge({ foo: 5 }, { foo: 'world' });
// const y: {
//     foo: number;
// } & {
//     foo: string;
// }
// But should be { foo: string }
```